# How to concatenate strings in php coming from the database table?

Tags: php

I have a `php code` as shown below in which I want to concatenate strings in php coming from the `database table`.

```
$record['INFO']['PATH_FILE'] = A:\RW\YVR;

$record['INFO']['FILE_NAME'] = abc.doc;
```

On `concatenation`, I want the string to look like this `A:\RW\16may05\abc.do`c  (I want to open/download a file on the click as its `href`)

**This is what I have tried:**

```
echo '        <td rowspan="'.$hello_world.'"><a href="'.$record['INFO']['PATH_FILE'].'"\"'.$record['INFO']['FILE_NAME'].'">'."\n";   // Line A
```

On inspect, I am seeing in the following format:

```
"A:\RW\YVR\abc.doc" \""=""
```

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what changes I need to make at Line A so that I see in the following format `"A:\RW\YVR\abc.doc"` or in the format in which users can open or download.

Answer (score 3):

The backslash will escape the next character, so you need to escape the backslash by using 2 backslashes

```
echo '<td rowspan="'.$hello_world.'"><a href="'.$record['INFO']['PATH_FILE'].'\\'.$record['INFO']['FILE_NAME'].'">'."\n";   // Line A
```